# ADF toggle required attribute from checkbox

Tags: oracle-adf

In my jsff file I have some input fields which are required by default. Now we want a way to toggle the required attribute using a checkbox. Several solutions have been tested, one of them like this:

```xml
<af:selectBooleanCheckbox id="sbc1" label="myLabel" value="#{sessionBean.skipInput}" autoSubmit="true"/>

<af:selectOneChoice label="myLabel" id="soc1" partialTriggers="sbc1" value="#{sessionScope.sessionBean.someValue}" required="#{!sessionBean.skipInput}">

<f:selectItems value="#{applicationScope.applicationBean.myItems}" id="si1"/>

</af:selectOneChoice>
```

When I check the checkbox to set the required attribute to false, the selectOneChoice will be red indicating that no value has been selected in the drowdown. How can I prevent this and simply remove the required attribute from the dropdown?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is the right approach, but the issue is that ADF can not change the checkbox value as long as the `required` constraint of the choice box is not fulfilled. So you will always get the "A selection is required" message and the new value of the check box will not be updated on the server as long as there is nothing selected in the choice box.

To solve this, you need to set the `immediate` property on the checkbox to `true` to skip validation, and add a `valueChangeListener` to handle the changes of the checkbox and manually call the render response phase:

```xml
<af:selectBooleanCheckbox id="sbc1" label="Skip Choice" 
                          value="#{sessionBean.skipInput}" 
                          autoSubmit="true"
                          immediate="true" 
                          valueChangeListener="#{sessionBean.toggleSkipInput}"/>
```

```java
public class SessionBean {

...

  public void toggleSkipInput(ValueChangeEvent vce) {
    setSkipInput(Boolean.TRUE.equals(vce.getNewValue()));
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().renderResponse();
  }
}
```

For more information, see

- http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/web.1111/b31973/af_lifecycle.htm#CIAHCFJF
- https://blogs.oracle.com/jdevotnharvest/entry/partial_submit_vs_auto_submit

Comment: Thanks, this wasn't quite enough. I had to add setRequired(false) in the backend to make it work but it still shows the red borders around the selectOneChoice.

Comment: Which version of ADF/JDeveloper are you using?

Comment: This works for me (with 11.1.2.3.0) - you can download the workspace with my sample application at https://github.com/afester/StackOverflow/tree/master/ADF/ToggleRequired

Comment: I can see that you example works fine but mine doesn't. I have done the same as you. Does it make a difference that my page is JSFF while your is JSPX?

Comment: That might make a difference - also, using the `immediate=true` attribute is usually discouraged, so I am not sure if my solution is 100% bullet proof. You also might want to review http://de.slideshare.net/stevendavelaar/18-invaluable-lessons-about-adfjsf-interaction.